# Optimized Distance Calculation for Data Cube

Tags: algorithm, matlab, matrix, linear-algebra

Is there an optimized solution for calculating a distance matrix for the distances between slices in a cube? For example, I have a data cube `C` with dimensions n×m×t. I want the `i`-th, `j`-th index of my distance matrix `D` to be equal to

```
D(i,j) = norm(C(:,:,i)-C(:,:,j))
```

And I'd like to do this non-iteratively.

Comment: IMHO aversion to using for loops in MATLAB is often misplaced: it's not inherently slow anymore.